# Angular: Child component listen for return after passing data to Parent component

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and have been trying to find what I need but unable to. Please help.

Let's say this is working function with required parameters:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  datatable(params, callback) {
    this.service.getList(params).subscribe(response => {
      callback({
        recordsTotal: response.recordsTotal,
        recordsFiltered: response.recordsFiltered,
        data: response.data
      });
    });
  }

  ...

}
```

The above are working fine. But then I want to make this ChildComponent as shared component so I have to separate this function and place it under ParentComponent. Please note that the codes below is incorrect but I'm trying to explain my point like this:

ChildComponent:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() source: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  datatable(params, callback) {
    this.source.emit(params, callback).subscribe(response => {
      callback({
        recordsTotal: response.recordsTotal,
        recordsFiltered: response.recordsFiltered,
        data: response.data
      });
    });
  }
  
  ...

}
```

ParentComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '
   <child-component (source)="getList($event)"></child-component>
  '
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private service: Service) { }
  
  getList(params) {
    return this.service.getList(params);
  }

}
```

Service:

```
export class Service {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getList(data) {
    return this.http.post("http://example.com/list", data)
  }
}
```

I know I'm doing wrongly. I need ChildComponent to pass parameter through ParentComponent's function and then listen for the return from there. How do I do that in correct way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using EventEmitter you defined it but not using

maybe

```
datatable(params, callback) {
  this.service.getList(params).subscribe(response => {
    callback({
      recordsTotal: response.recordsTotal,
      recordsFiltered: response.recordsFiltered,
      data: response.data
    });

    this.source.emit('what ever you want to pass');
  });
}
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '
   <child-component (source)="getList($event)"></child-component>
  '
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private service: Service) { }
  
  getList(params) {
    return this.service.getList(params).subscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct as I have tried it. EventEmitter actually seems not supporting subscribe after emit part but are there other ways to do it correctly?

Comment: @the14thsky yes there was a mistake in my example, now its fixed, if you could send a https://stackblitz.com/ sample would be great

Comment: thanks for reply. here is the sample code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpwgn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts
Please take a look at the comment I stated in codes.

Comment: try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a3scgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: The codes you have provided did not include any subscribe which I need it to subscribe to service after calling the function from parent component.

Comment: Once you call your child component method, will be emited as output to the parent component, then parent component method will be triggered and excecute service, see console logs

Comment: That is one-way pass. I wanted the child component to receive the data back from the parent component after emitting. Once the parent got emitted event from child, it will be triggered and execute service then pass data back to child component which has been listening for.

Comment: Anyway I found a solution already. The child component function will emit event and also subscribe to Subject under service which the parent component has to use Subject next method to send the data after executed. Then the child will get the data from Subject.